# Doxygen latex formulas eating space

Tags: latex, doxygen, equation

I have been using `@f$\langle PROGRAM MESSAGE UNIT \rangle@f$` to produce documentation that *should* result in pdf output of `<PROGRAM MESSAGE UNIT>`.

However it is actually resulting in `<PROGRAMMESSAGEUNIT>`. How do I get it to stop eating the spaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my google query on this was a bit off. As I've put these in as formulas latex tries to decide it's own spacing, thus it needs to be forced:

\; = thick space, \: = thin space

src: http://www.personal.ceu.hu/tex/math.htm

Update: Just found that I can use markdown back ticks to enclose the angle brackets and avoid the tex altogether. Yay.

Comment: You should see [What commands are there for horizontal spacing?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74353/5764)